# Rails 5 use belongs_to with condition for different tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails app, with different tables and associations, and trying to find out the best solution for that, don't know yet.

One table/class is called categories

For example

```
Categories
  - Stocks
  - Reits
  -(...)
```

One table for each category

```
Stocks
  belongs_to :category
```

```
Reits
  belongs_to :category
```

Than i want to create a table called "Dividends", with a condition, don't know if is possible, for example:

```
Dividends

  belongs_to :category

  if category_id == 1
    belongs_to :stock
  end

  if category_id == 2
    belongs_to :reit
  end
```

With the command:

```
rails g scaffold dividends category:references stock:references reit:references
```

But i don't know if it would be confusing, an if maybe would be better create a table for each class, for example:

```
StocksDividends
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :stock

ReitsDividends
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :reit
```

Would like some help on thinking about that solution.

Comment: There is no single answer to the question. Its really a matter of tradeoffs. Do you want simplicity? Referential integrity? To be able to query it as a homogenenius collection? The "best" solution depends entirely on how you are going to use it.

Comment: If you don't need to query it as a homogenous collection you already have the simplest and most straight forward solution which avoids a lot of the cons of polymorphic assocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a quick hint - take a look at polymorphic associations:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

The mechanics of it put a foreign key in the dividends table along with a `type` column. The `type` column tells you what type of record is the parent - the `stock` or the `reit`.

Comment: That's interesting, maybe i could work, would be something like: dividendable ?

Comment: The big con of polymorphic assocations is that very few databases allow compound foreign key constraints so they don't provide referential integrity.

Comment: @max true! I sometimes use a compound index to help with that. Something like:
`add_index :<table>, %i[column_one column_two], unique: true`

Comment: That won't really help with referential integrity - just with maintaining uniqueness. You can still get orphaned records in the table.

Comment: You could also just subclass the category so your category model would have a `type` column and your stock class would look like `class Stock < Category`. See [this](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/03/rails-single-table-inheritance/). I dont know what youre trying to do exactly but it looks like you need conditional logic for different types of categories and thats exactly what this would solve